# анимация не работает в хроме

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, dom, gsap

есть такая конструкция

```
<object id="logotop" data="images/logo10.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

к ней написан такой код:

```
window.onload = function() {

var logotop = document.getElementById("logotop"),
    svgDoclogotop = logotop.getSVGDocument(),
    line = svgDoclogotop.querySelectorAll('#line');

var d5 = new TimelineMax();
d5
    .staggerFrom(line, 0.5, {drawSVG:"0 0%"}, .5);
};
```

использую  `querySelectorAll` потому что элементов `#line` много

в мозиле все работает, в хроме нет.
если встроить svg в html - -все отлично. но так как svg весит 316кб, будет очнь длинный не читаемый код.

что можно сделать? спасибо!

Comment: `line = svgDoclogotop.querySelectorAll('#line');`  `Id` на странице может быть один единственный или  ты ошибся и надо было написать `line = svgDoclogotop.querySelector('#line');` без - `All`. Ну а если у тебя `ID` - не в единственном экземпляре, то замени их на `class="line"`

Comment: да, с id  конечно ступил... поставил querySelector но то же эффект  - хроме не работает(

Comment: Лучше покажи нормально, что да как ты делаешь, а то по огрызку данного кода не понятно, что должно работать, какую ошибку выдает, что именно происходит...

Comment: Ты заменил `querySelectorAll` на `querySelector`  я не вижу что у тя внутри там твориться, но `querySelector` - будет видеть только первый элемент

Comment: `использую  querySelectorAll потому что элементов #line много` - это твои слова... так замени обратно на `line = svgDoclogotop.querySelectorAll('#line');`  но в место `id` используй  `class`  - `line = svgDoclogotop.querySelectorAll('.line');`

Comment: не работает в хроме - везде работает без проблем.
и с этим querySelectorAll
и с этим getElementsByClassName
и даже  когда было много одинаковых id  - везде кроме хрома работает(

в консоли getSVGDocument() выдает - null

Answer (score 2):

Решено!
оказалось что

```
getSVGDocument()
```

работает в хроме только если закинуть файлы на сервер. просто из папки не работает.

Comment: Это очень хорошо, что сами нашли причину. (+) Странно, что никто не подсказал вам раньше, это довольно известный факт.